# Coding new Appointment behind a button with the scheduler control in devexpress

Tags: devexpress

I'm new here and to devexpress and my Question I hope is a simple one to all you mavericks here. I'm creating an scheduling module with devexpress and I want to add a"necessary appointment "button rather than having to right click to add an appointment..users love buttons after all and I can't seem to find code for that..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SchedulerControl.CreateAppointment](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_CreateAppointmenttopic) method, that creates a new appointment with the specified All-Day and Recurring settings, shows it in the Edit Appointment dialog, and then adds it to the [SchedulerStorage.Appointments](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerStorage_Appointmentstopic) collection of the control's storage.

Comment: Thank you very much..it worked perfectly..I'll get a hang of devexpress soon enough..